# In React Native app passing navigation to class component puts it in another navigation object

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

In my React Native app, when I pass `navigation` to a class component, it puts it in another `navigation` object and now I have to add one more `navigation` to call the `navigate()` method.

So, instead of `this.props.navigation.navigate("somewhere")`,
I have to use `this.props.navigation.navigation.navigate("somewhere")`

Here's how I pass `navigation` from a functional to a class component:

```
const ParentComponent = ({ navigation }) => {
   return(
      <View>
          <ChildComponent navigation={navigation} />
      </View>
   );
}

export default ParentComponent;
```

And in the child component which happens to be a class component with access to Redux store, I recieve `navigation` like this:

```
class ChildComponent extends Component {

   render() {
      return(
         <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigation.navigate("Route123")}>
                <Text>Go to Route 123</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
         </View>
      );
   }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, navigation) {
   myAccount: state.account.myAccount,
   navigation: navigation
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ChildComponent);
```

Notice that in the `ChildComponent`, I had to add one more `navigation` to access the `navigate` function i.e. `this.props.navigation.navigation.navigate("Route123");`

I think I'm making a fairly fundamental mistake somewhere but not sure where.

The version of React Navigation in my app is as follows and the React Native version is `0.66.3`:

```
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
"@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
```

Comment: how come `navigation` is part of `mapStateToProps`? and why do you pass `navigation` as a prop instead of using `withNaviagtion` HOC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Hagai Harari stated, you should not put navigation as the second parameter of mapStateToProps function. As described [here](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate), second parameter of mapStateProps takes ownProps which corresponds to the component props.

You can use [withNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/with-navigation/). But when I see your dependencies, you are using `react-navigation@^6` which does not have HOC called as `withNavigation`.

You can choose to use `this.props.navigation` after removing unnecessary `navigation` param from `mapStateToProps`.

What I would suggest is to use functional component instead of class components, then you will be able to use [useNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/) which `react-navigation@^6` exposes. In the end, you will obtain navigation object without repetition of passing it down to children components.

Comment: You're right about NOT passing `navigation` to `mapStateToProps` but in some cases class components won't have access to `navigation` so we still pass it to a class component but there's no need to reference it in `mapStateToProps`. Here's the correct way to pass `navigation` to class components: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation#using-with-class-component As per not using class components, I'm not on board with that. I think class components make accessing the Redux store and action creators very easy. Thanks for telling me about NOT sending `navigation` to `mapStateToProps`

Comment: You can easily access redux store and actions with hooks. Even easier than the class components. Please take a look at this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpw9EHDh2bM&ab_channel=ReactConf

Comment: Redux hooks, https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks